# Error: Implementing AntiCrossSiteForgery POST Request from Angular6 to ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Good day,

I'm receiving a `400 bad request` while sending post request on my ASP.NET Core Web API 2.1.

[image]

[image]

I have 2 projects. First is Angular6 as my rest client and second is my ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API as my rest server.

To show you what I've done, here is my angular spa codes:

I have a method that fetches the token on my api. It returns a string

```
saveAntiForgeryToken(){
    this.getToken().subscribe((response: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('antiforgerytoken', response.token);
    }, error => {
    console.log(`Something went wrong ${error}`);
    });
}
```

On my post service, I have this code:

```
submitInfo(info: any){
     this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}Info`, info, {
        headers: {
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': localStorage.getItem('antiforgerytoken')
        }
    });
}
```

While on my ASP.NET Core Web API, I made few changes on my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    ... 
    app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/")
        {
        //send the request token as a JavaScript-readable cookie, and Angular will use it by default
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("X-XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
         }
         return next(context);
    });
}
```

On my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Info info) { ... }
```

Lastly, the api code method responsible for fetching antiforgerytoken

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> RetrieveToken()
{
    var retrievedToken = await Task.FromResult(
         new {
                token = antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken
    });
    return Ok(retrievedToken);
}
```

Please help. I stuck with this for days. :(

Comment: Are you sure your just not using an old token?

Comment: As I see on my network request tab, I'm getting a new token. I put a console before the http.post to see if the token is changing, as I see, it's new token @johnny5

Comment: sir @johnny5 and sir kirk, I added a new photo above. I tried 3 times in posting the form

Comment: This is all covered in the docs. Follow that, and you'll be fine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1#javascript-ajax-and-spas

Comment: Oh okay sir @KirkLarkin

Comment: I added the api code method responsible for getting the token on the last section of my question sir @KirkLarkin

Comment: There's no reason to have a specific endpoint for returning the token - that's what the middleware you added is for. At this stage, I''m going to go with @ChrisPratt and suggest you go through the docs carefully, from the start.

Comment: Actually, doesn't having an API endpoint that returns antiforgery tokens pretty much entirely moot the point of using antiforgery tokens? If I'm a malicious user and want to post something to your site, I can just request a token and then send my real request with that immediately afterwards.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I need to restrict that request too.

Comment: So what do you propose a better solution? @ChrisPratt

Comment: I'm honestly not clear what you're trying to achieve here. Antiforgery protection is usually not compatible with an API, since the whole point of an API is generally to allow third-party access. If the API is only intended to be accessed by your application(s), then you make the application authorize its requests with something like a client id/secret. Using antiforgery only enforces that the client visited another page on your site to make the post, it doesn't prevent outside users from making posts entirely.

Comment: Thank you for that info. I'm newbie when it comes to Angular6. Especially now, I separate my project into two pieces. Angular6 SPA and ASP.NET Core Web API. So, it means, I don't necessary need to implement Antiforgery from Angular to my web api in every post and put request? Can I ask you another question, how do you implement antiforgery from Angular app to your web api?

Comment: How do you get the token from the rest server api and send it to rest client (in my case, on my angular spa app?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPratt can I ask a question?